# can't get response header location using Java's URLConnection

Tags: java, http, urlconnection

can someone kindly suggest what I'm doing wrong here?
I'm trying to get the header location for a certain URL using Java
here is my code:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
String location = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
```

it's strange since I know for sure the URL i'm refering to return a Location header and using methods like getContentType() or getContentLength() works perfectly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps `Location` header is returned as a part of redirect response. If so, `URLConnection` handles redirect automatically by issuing the second request to the pointed resource, so you need to disable it:

```
((HttpURLConnection) conn).setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

**EDIT:**
If you actually need a URL of the redirect target and don't want to disable redirect handling, you may call `getURL()` instead (after connection is established).

Comment: it works in most cases. However, it does not work for this url: https://db.tt/4do5q7Tk.  However, you do are able to see the header from this online too: http://www.srccodes.com/tools/html/http-headers-viewer

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up to [axtavt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103154/axtavt) answer... If the url has multiple redirects, you could do something like this in order to obtain the direct link:

```
String location = "http://www.example.com/download.php?getFile=1";
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
for (;;) {
    URL url = new URL(location);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    String redirectLocation = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
    if (redirectLocation == null) break;
    location = redirectLocation;
}
```