# Downloading pdf in WebView Android

Tags: android, android-webview, okhttp

I have a HTML page that contains a form with a submit button like the following:

```
<form action="https://www.myUrl.com/test.html" method="POST">
   <input class="submit" type="submit" title="PDF (165 KB)" value="PDF (165 KB)">
</form>
```

When clicking on the submit button from a desktop, a PDF file is downloaded. However, when clicking the same button in the Android WebView, the same PDF file is not being downloaded.
When requesting the Url after clicking the same button, I'm always getting `text/html` as `Content-Type`

I tried requesting the url with different methods:

1. HttpUrlConnection:

   ```
   ucon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", params[1]);
   ucon.setRequestMethod(params[2]);
   ucon.connect();
   String resource = ucon.getContentType();
   ```
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886313/get-the-final-url-of-a-redirected-request-with-unconventional-scheme)
3. [An injected OkHttpClient](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

All three methods are returning the same Content-Type.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Send a request using postman to the pdf, and check the content type.

Comment: I'm sending the request to this URL https://www.myUrl.com/test.html because I don't know what is the exact PDF url

Comment: Go to chrome downloads page `CTRL + J` and you will see the link there.

Comment: @AMD It is the same link as in the form.

Comment: So then it is a post request, and returns a PDF when the parameters are set correctly. You can try to check the parameters from chrome dev tools. Also try using chrome for Android and see if it works there.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting application/pdf. How to return the last requested url to send it to the download task? I'm using OkHttpClient

Comment: @AMD Thank you I managed to download it